# Python Numpy - Matrix memory error and limits

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

after I have been searching this topic on the web, I saw that I was not the only one to have this problem but I can't understand if there is a way to overcome the problem or not.

I have 5036 text files and a word list of 15985 words. For each word of the word list found on the text file, I would like to put a 1 on my matrix. But I get the error : *MemoryError*.

I tried also just to create the matrix and make a print (in case of a bug in my python code).. I got the same error.
Any suggestions?

```
matrix = np.zeros(shape=(5036,15985))
```

Edit: That's my code maybe there are some errors..
It should work in this way:

1. create the dictionary from a file (each word on the text file is
   names as "1_word1 2_word2 " etc, so splitting each line of the text
   file I will have in split_[0] the position in matrix, in split_[1]
   the word itself)
2. for each text file it saves the number of the file in order to put
   the right document on the matrix (each text file is named
   “1_1A_out.txt   2_1A_out.txt etc”)
3. finally it prints the matrix.

   ```
   import os
   import re
   import fileinput
   import numpy as np

   matrix = np.zeros(shape=(6000,16000))

   def dictionary_creation (filepath):
       fileopen = open(filepath, "r")
       dictionary = fileopen.read().split('\n')
       fileopen.close()
       return dictionary


   def find_doc_matrix_position (filename):
       regex = re.compile('(\d)_(.*)')
       find_regex = regex.search(file)
       if find_regex:
           pos_doc = int(find_regex.group(1))-1
       return pos_doc

   def put_nbdoc_nbword_in_matrix (filename, dictionary, nb_file):
       for line in fileinput.input([filename]):
               line = line.replace("\n", "")
               for w in range(0,len(dictionary)-1):
                   split_ = dictionary[w].split('_',1)              
                   if line == split_[1]:
   #                    print ("nb_file is: "+str(nb_file))                    
   #                    print ("nb_word is : "+str(split_[0]))
   #                    print ("line is: "+line+" word is: "+split_[1])
   #                    print '####'
                       matrix[nb_file,split_[0]] = 1

   dictionary = dictionary_creation('C:\\Users\\KP\\Desktop\\FSC_lemmes_sort.txt')

   for file in os.listdir('C:\Users\KP\Desktop\FSC_Treetag\out'):
           fin = open(file, 'r')
           filename = file
           nb_file = find_doc_matrix_position(file)
           put_nbdoc_nbword_in_matrix(filename, dictionary, nb_file)

   print "this is the final matrix\n"
   print matrix
   ```

Comment: 5036*15985*4/1024/1024 = 307 MB (assuming 4 bytes for each matrix entry).  What else is your app doing?  Is this 32 or 64 bit Python?

Comment: @duffymo 32 Maybe it's better to post the code

Comment: What is the complete error message that you get?

Comment: `np.zeros` defaults to floats, which on my system are 24 bytes (unlike the 4 bytes assumed by @duffymo) -- you can check this with `sys.getsizeof`.  You might want to try using a [bitarray](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray) since you only need one bit per item in your array.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix 


`File "C:/Users/KP/Desktop/FSC_Treetag/out/f3_test_from_files_to_matrix_fonctions.py", line 6, in <module>
    matrix = np.zeros(shape=(5037,15999))
MemoryError`

Comment: Why would anyone store (0, 1) as float?

Comment: Aside from the inefficient datatype of that zeroes - If even this `matrix = np.zeros(shape=(5036,15985))` test fails. we don't have to debug your code yet. **How exactly did you (or your package maintainer) build your numpy package?**

Comment: The are many SO questions about building word occurance arrays using the `scipy` `sparse` matrix module.  Your array has a lot more zeros than ones.

Comment: @decltype_auto I don't know hot to answer to your question .. Can you explain me better what are you asking me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the specific error message:

> File
>   "C:/Users/KP/Desktop/FSC_Treetag/out/f3_test_from_files_to_matrix_fonctions.py",
>   line 6, in  matrix = np.zeros(shape=(5037,15999)) MemoryError

You don't have enough memory to allocate the array.  Depending on your system, each value in your `matrix` will be using something like 8 bytes, so this array should only occuryp about 600 MB of memory... which really isn't much.  Likely there are other things (processes, open files, etc) that are eating up all of your system memory.

At the same time, since you are just finding whether each word exists or not in the file, you only need a single bit for each file-word entry in the matrix.  In that case you should simply [use a bitarray](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray) (i.e. a single bit for each entry).

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a memory error probably because your matrix is too big, or you don't have enough available RAM memory in your computer.

You can try to iterate across all your text files, so you just need to create a matrix like:

```
matrix = np.zeros(shape=(15985))
```

and then save the result to a file for every of your texts.